# How does the client of an Express app know the server's address?

Tags: rest, express

I am fairly new to web development.

I have an express server, that serves a little web app (static).
Now I want it the web app to consume a RESTful API from the server. But how does the client know how to call home? I am pretty sure that hardcoding the IP is a bad idea. Is there any way to let the web app know from where it was served?

My server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routerAPI = express.Router();

app.use('/', express.static('webApp'));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static('bower_components'));
app.use('/api', routerAPI);

routerAPI.get('/getStuff', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({test: 'test'});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your server file, so I can understand how you have achieved the serving of static files? Is the API built within the same express server utilising express router?

Comment: So, if I understand your question correctly. You want the web app to be able to consume your new api. It can do so inherently, since it understands where the root `/` is, and as such, if your api is behind the `/api/` route, then it will access them without any trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're serving both the web app and the API from the same HTTP server (running on port 3000), just use relative paths.

In other words, your client can use `/getStuff` directly, without the need for scheme, hostname or port in the URL.

Comment: Even though the webapp is executed in the local browser and the API on the server?

Comment: @Moezalez yeah, because the server serves the client code as well, and both the client code and the API code share the same server in that respect.

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this? Awesome! Thanks!